# MongoDB Query Optimization using Multiple $lookup's and $group

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is a simplified schema of the database I am working with:

```
Collection: documents
{
   "_Id": "1",
   "business": "e.g food",
   "relationships": "192",
   "components": "ObjectId(34927493..)",
   "_Score": "10",
   ...
}

Collection: components
{
   "_Id": "280948304320",
   "assessments": "8394",
   "relationships": "192",
   "results":"ObjectId("82394792343")...."// can be many results
}

Collection: results
{
   "_Id": "7978394243",
   "state": "severe",
   "parentComponent": "ObjectId("28907403")"
   "confidence":"0.5"
   "category":"Inspection"
}
```

I have a `mongoDB` query which is taking 200+ seconds to execute. Here it is below:

```
db.documents.aggregate([
{$match:
   { "business" : "food"}
},
{
   $unwind: "$components"
},
{
  $lookup:
    {
      from: "components",
      localField: "components",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "matching_components"
    }
},
{
   $unwind: "$matching_components"
},
{
   $lookup:
   {
         from: "results",
         localField: "components",
         foreignField: "parentComponent",
         as: "list_results"
   }
},
{
   $unwind: "$list_results"
},
{$group :
   { _id : '$list_results.state', count : {$sum : 1}}
}
])
```

I am wondering if there is any way for me to improve the performance of this query. I tried using a `group` statement in the beginning of the query that groups the documents into their `business` category, but that did not work as I realized it removes the fields needed for the rest of the query. I indexed for all the fields that I am looking across.

Just to be clear I want to group the documents by their `business` field. Then I want to map to another collection called `components` that contains `results`. After I use another lookup to finally map to the `results` collection, I want to ultimately count the frequency of each `state` by `business`. Currently as you can see, I am using a `match` in the beginning instead just to see if the query works for one `business` type. Though the query works, it is taking around 140 seconds.

EDIT: Example Result from this Aggregation:

```
{
   "_id" : State1",
   "count" : 90699.0
}

{
   "_id" : "State2",
   "count" : 448869.0
}


{
   "_id" : "State3",
   "count" : 71399.0
}


{
   "_id" : "State4",
   "count" : 513928.0
}


{
   "_id" : "State5",
   "count" : 765509.0
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `matching_components` in your example? It's not being used at all at the moment. Also, could you provide an example result of this aggregation?

Comment: @RadosławMiernik The purpose of `matching_components` was to find all the components of an application and then unwind the array. I edited the original post with an example result of the aggregation.

Comment: So either the second `$lookup` phase should use `localField: 'matching_components'` or the first `$lookup` + `$unwind` pair is not needed. What is the case here?

Comment: @RadosławMiernik I tried using the `localField: 'matching_components` as you suggested but it still took a significant amount of time to execute the query. Im afraid the way this database is designed it is very difficult for me to efficiently execute this aggregation

Comment: It is still slow, but the results may be different. Which one returned correct results?